# import.io URL returns

Tags: api, import.io

I'm using Import.io to catalogue assets on a client's blog.

I've got it all working nicely and I'm seeing some great results but when I do a Bulk Extract I'm getting a handful of results less than I put in, around 145 versus the 150 or so I input.

I tracked this down and found a number of the URLs had since changed, I sorted that with another step to the call.

Now I know I'm testing correct URLs but I'm still getting the same outcome, albeit 148 versus 150 now.

I have to track down manually which ones haven't been returned as import.io just says 148 URLs returned. When I have tracked them down and query them individually, they always work fine.

Has anyone else had this problem? I have to train several teams on this very soon and they will struggle with this step.

I've asked their support team but no one has come back yet. Anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4):

You are right: manually figuring out which URLs are failing and then re-querying them through "Bulk Extract" is the only way to make sure you get all your data.

I work for Import.io, and we are working on a "retry failed URLs" option in Bulk Extract which will be released soon and should solve that issue. It's a relatively new feature and we are still working out some kinks.